# PHP: How to remove key from assoc array while leaving values intact

Tags: php

I have an array like this.

```
array('root'=> array(
      'auth'=>'stringKey',
       'version'=>'4057',
       '...'=>'...'
  )
  )
```

Now I want to remove the outer array and  `root` key and so I get array like below. i.e reduce it to one dimensional array

```
array(
  'auth'=>'stringKey',
   'version'=>'4057',
   '...'=>'...'
)
```

Comment: `$myArray = $myArray['root'];`

Comment: @MarkBaker copy to new array?. is there any better way to modify array in place as these are results from api calls and am worried about eating up memory

Comment: you can see my answer it works as you said

Comment: Better way! Why do you need it, because you can always directly reference the sub-array anyway using `$myArray['root']`... but I doubt if any other approach will be faster or more memory efficient

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(
      'root'=> array(
           'auth'=>'stringKey',
           'version'=>'4057',
           '...'=>'...'
       )
);

print_r($array['root']);
```

Comment: if the array is large, will the performance not degrade as there is coping involved

Comment: Maybe half of a millisecond slower. It shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this it is work for me

```
    <?php $myarr = array('root'=> array(
              'auth'=>'stringKey',
               'version'=>'4057',
               '...'=>'...'
          )
          );

        $array = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$myarr);
        print_r($array);

/*
output 

Array
(
    [auth] => stringKey
    [version] => 4057
    [...] => ...
)


*/
    ?>
```

Comment: let me do online example for you

Comment: you can see [click here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/USHYNGROBF)

Comment: its assuming there are multiple arrays as level one:

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the existing variable with the :

```
$myarray = array('root'=> array(
      'auth'=>'stringKey',
       'version'=>'4057',
       '...'=>'...'
  )
  )

$myarray = $myarray['root'];
```

[Check demo](https://eval.in/723775)